# django template - how to get a dictionary property without using a for loop

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates, django-views

Doing this works

```
{% for comment in comments %}
{{ comment.user }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I want to get all the comment.user values in the dictionary without using a for loop. Is this possible?

I ask because I need to do this check

```
{% if name in comment.user %} # check if name is in any one of the comments 
# do something
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to get all the distinct users from comments. You have to do it in the view and pass users queryset back into the template:

```
users = User.objects.filter(comment__in=comments).distinct()
```

Comment: this won't work, as I'm comparing Facebook friends gotten from the Graph API and comparing them to the existing comments

Comment: please, edit your question and add more information because otherwise it is not possible to answer the question. Insert some info about models and views you use and also about how you get friends from api.